# Validate requests parameters using swagger-express-middleware

Tags: node.js, express, swagger, middleware

new to nodeJS swagger middleware. I have what probably seem like a question with probably an obvious answer. I have been shopping around for a library and swagger-express-middleware seem to have some build-in tools for handling request validations.

I have a very straight forward endpoint:

```
/ping:
get:
  x-swagger-router-controller: health-check
  description: Health check endpoint.
  operationId: getPing
  responses:
    "200":
      description: This service is healthy.
      schema:
        $ref: '#/definitions/PingResponse'
    default:
      description: Error payload.
      schema:
        $ref: '#/definitions/ErrorMessage'
```

In this init function of the service I do something like this

```
        this.middleware.init(swaggerPath, (err) => {
        this.app.use(
            this.middleware.metadata(),
            this.middleware.CORS(),
            this.middleware.files(),
            this.middleware.parseRequest(),
            this.middleware.validateRequest(),
        );
    });
```

If I then run a curl like this

```
curl --url "http://localhost:9000/ping?hello=true"
```

I would expect to get an error, however it returns a valid response. Does the framework only check for defined parameters and checks if they are there or not based on requirement settings or is it also capable of checking for unknown parameters like above. If so do I need add any code in the init phase? Or is there a better library for request validation?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is because you include the query string in path, which is not considered in the OpenAPI standard:

https://swagger.io/docs/specification/paths-and-operations/

> OpenAPI considers a unique operation as a combination of a path and the HTTP method, and additional parameters do not make the operation unique.

This also means that it is impossible to have multiple paths that differ only in query string, such as:

```
GET /users?firstName=value&lastName=value
GET /users?role=value
```

My guess is that Swagger returns the route that it found and ignore your parameters.